# Can't update existing Doctrine entity

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I'm working with **symfony 2.7** form component to update an entity called `TapsAlert`.
The problem, is the entity is not updated after submitting the form.
 I don't know what is going wrong. Here's a part of code:

```
public function editarRegistroAction(Request $request, $id){

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $altd = $em->getRepository('ModeloBundle:TapsAlert')->find($id);

    $altd->setAsunto($altd->getAsunto());
    $altd->setGls($altd->getGls());
    $altd->setDestinatario($altd->getDestinatario());
    $altd->setPrts($altd->getPrts());
    $altd->setTags($altd->getTags());
    $altd->setValor($altd->getValor());

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($altd)
        ->add('Asunto', 'text')
        ->add('gls', 'text')
        ->add('destinatario', 'text')
        //->add('dias', 'number')
        ->add('prts', 'text')
        ->add('Tags', 'text')
        ->add('valor', 'text')
        ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Guardar Cambios'))
        ->getForm();

        //$form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            //$edAlert = $form->getData();
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            //$em->persist($altd);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect('http://192.168.1.128/');
        }

    return $this->render('MotoBundle:Default:edit.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First:** this part of code is useless. It should be removed:

```
$altd->setAsunto($altd->getAsunto());
$altd->setGls($altd->getGls());
$altd->setDestinatario($altd->getDestinatario());
$altd->setPrts($altd->getPrts());
$altd->setTags($altd->getTags());
$altd->setValor($altd->getValor());
```

**Second**: You are not handling your request:

```
  public function editarRegistroAction(Request $request, $id){
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $altd = $em->getRepository('ModeloBundle:TapsAlert')->find($id);

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($altd)
            ->add('Asunto', 'text')
            ->add('gls', 'text')
            ->add('destinatario', 'text')
            //->add('dias', 'number')
            ->add('prts', 'text')
            ->add('Tags', 'text')
            ->add('valor', 'text')
            ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Guardar Cambios'))
            ->getForm();

            $form->handleRequest($request); //uncomment this line
            if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                $em->flush();

                return $this->redirect('http://192.168.1.128/'); // This url should an be an external url
            }

        return $this->render('MotoBundle:Default:edit.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
    }
```

**Third:** I beleive that you can improve your code, with [paramConvertor](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html):

```
  public function editarRegistroAction(Request $request, TapsAlert $tapsAlert){

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($tapsAlert)
            ->add('Asunto', 'text')
            ->add('gls', 'text')
            ->add('destinatario', 'text')
            //->add('dias', 'number')
            ->add('prts', 'text')
            ->add('Tags', 'text')
            ->add('valor', 'text')
            ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Guardar Cambios'))
            ->getForm();

            $form->handleRequest($request);
            if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

                return $this->redirect('http://192.168.1.128/'); // This url should an be an external url
            }

        return $this->render('MotoBundle:Default:edit.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
    }
```

It's a better practice, also, to build the form in a separate class, for more details, take a look to the official documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-form-classes

Comment: thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it's not working

Comment: Could you specify what is not working? Are you redirected to the `http://192.168.1.128/` ? Do you get any exception ?

Comment: sorry bro, it's working, but i had to clear the cache, and about the code improvement, i'm new with symfony, i'll get better with time thank you

Comment: Happy to help. Let me know if you need more clarifications Have a good day, any time :)